# Evaluate the integral $\int\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^3 + 3x + 1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral 
$$\int\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^3 + 3x + 1} dx$$

I've looked at similar examples online and I can't find one like the one above. In class we did one where we had to do long division and rewrite the function, but that one and all the examples I've found online would have the $x^2 + 1$ in the denominator, making long division easier. I don't know how to approach this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $u=x^3+3x+1$ and see the magic.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^3 + 3x + 1} dx=\dfrac{1}{3}\int\frac{3(x^2 + 1)}{x^3 + 3x + 1} dx=\\
\dfrac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{x^3 + 3x + 1} d(x^3 + 3x + 1)=\dfrac{1}{3}\ln\left|x^3 + 3x + 1\right|+C$$